# How to convert HTML to PDF using jsPDF when HTML content is too long?

Tags: jspdf, html2canvas, html-to-pdf

I want to convert html to pdf. For this I use the jsPDF library. But my HTML changes dynamically and it can be too long. HTML text is truncated when it is long. I am trying to convert pdf pages with multiple pages inside.

This is my current code:

```
async function generatePdfFromHtml(htmlElement) {
            // Create a new div element to hold the HTML content
            const div = document.createElement('div');
            div.innerHTML = htmlElement;

            // Append the div element to the document body
            document.body.appendChild(div);

            // Convert the HTML content to a canvas element
            const canvas = await html2canvas(div);
            const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

            const pdf = new jsPDF("p", "pt", "a4", true);
            const pageWidth = pdf.internal.pageSize.width;
            const pageHeight = (canvas.height * pageWidth) / canvas.width;
            pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, 0, pageWidth, pageHeight);
            pdf.save('myfile.pdf');

            // Remove the temporary div element from the document body
            document.body.removeChild(div);
        }
```

I will add an exported pdf example here too:

[image]